# Reusable error-squared minimizer func for multiple variables

Tags: vb.net, lambda, regression, least-squares

I'm trying to solve for three variables in a mathematical formula. The [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_parameter_product#Measurement) is as follows:

```vb
Dim secondMomentOfBeam As Func(Of Beamμ2params, Double, Double) =
    Function(params, z)
        Return params.σ0 ^ 2 + (params.M2 ^ 2) * Math.Pow(λ / (Math.PI * params.σ0), 2) * Math.Pow(z - params.z0, 2)
    End Function
```

using

```vb
Friend Class Beamμ2params
    Public σ0 As Double
    Public z0 As Double
    Public M2 As Double

    Public Sub New(ByVal sigmaNot As Double, ByVal zNot As Double, ByVal Msquared As Double)
        Me.σ0 = sigmaNot
        Me.z0 = zNot
        Me.M2 = Msquared
    End Sub
End Class
```

I need to create a loop which dithers each variable, σ0, z0, and M2, then checks the overall error-squared, then either repeats or finishes, depending on the error-squared.

```vb
While errorSquared > 1
    ' minimize error with σ0 
    ' minimize error with z0 
    ' minimize error with M2 
End While
```

Instead of hard-coding this loop for each variable (and having a lot of identical code blocks) I'd prefer to have a function which can minimize *any* of the variables, depending on a lambda which selects the variable, called like this

```vb
Dim minimizeErrorSquared As Func(Of Beamμ2params, Func(Of Beamμ2params, Double), Double, UInt32, Beamμ2params) =
    Function(params, selector, dither, iterations)
        ' dither value chosen by selector
        ' check error-squared
        ' dither toward zero
        ' up to max iterations
    End Function
```

with `selector`, the second argument, selecting which variable will be dithered. This makes my loop now look like

```vb
Dim params As New Beamμ2params(σ0initial, z0initial, M2initial)
While errorSquared > 1
    params = minimizeErrorSquared(params, Function(p As Beamμ2params) p.σ0, 0.01, 10)
    params = minimizeErrorSquared(params, Function(p As Beamμ2params) p.z0, 5, 10)
    params = minimizeErrorSquared(params, Function(p As Beamμ2params) p.M2, 0.05, 10)
    ' calculate error squared based on raw data and params
End While
```

The problem I can't wrap my head around is how to apply a new variable value to the appropriate variable inside `minimizeErrorSquared`, then return the params with the new variable changed. I have tried a Delegate with `ByRef` arguments (nothing worth pasting here) but can't quite pass the new variable value back to the main loop. I'm looking for suggestions on how to finish my train of thought conceptually, or someone to come at it from a different angle and suggest a different paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution, but the one I don't want. Ideally, the three Funcs should be written as one Func. Looking for a better solution

```
Dim minimizeErrorSquaredσ0 As Func(Of Beamμ2params, Double, UInt32, Beamμ2params) =
    Function(params, dither, iterations)
        ' minimize error-squared using params.σ0
    End Function

Dim minimizeErrorSquaredz0 As Func(Of Beamμ2params, Double, UInt32, Beamμ2params) =
    Function(params, dither, iterations)
        ' minimize error-squared using params.z0
    End Function

Dim minimizeErrorSquaredM2 As Func(Of Beamμ2params, Double, UInt32, Beamμ2params) =
    Function(params, dither, iterations)
        ' minimize error-squared using params.M2
    End Function

Try
    Dim errorSquared As Double = Double.MaxValue
    Dim params As New Beamμ2params(σ0initial, z0initial, M2initial)
    While errorSquared > 1
        params = minimizeErrorSquaredσ0(params, 0.01, 10)
        params = minimizeErrorSquaredz0(params, 5, 10)
        params = minimizeErrorSquaredM2(params, 0.1, 10)
        ' calculate error squared based on raw data and params
    End While
    Finally
End Try
```